# How to run a shell script placed in different folder from python

Tags: python

I am using the subprocess.call like below:

subprocess.call(['sudo ./order_fc_prioritizer/run.sh'])

But its saying no such file or directory

Comment: Could you show us what your directory structure looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an absolute, as opposed to relative, file path to your script.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a list to `call()` with the command and arguments split into separate list elements:

```
subprocess.call(['sudo', './order_fc_prioritizer/run.sh'])
```

See the documentation, section [Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
>   of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
>   preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
>   escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
>   names). If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see
>   below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
>   without specifying any arguments.

You could also use `shlex.split()` to create the argument list:

```
import shlex

subprocess.call(shlex.split('sudo ./order_fc_prioritizer/run.sh'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `subprocess.Popen()`

Basically `subprocess.call()` is just an helper function to:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=PATH)
proc.wait()
```

but Popen() has a keyword argument cwd that's the working directory where to execute the command (spawn the process).